Why do we care about the STFT of a signal?
As far as I know, the STFT is used to analyze the frequency content of a non-stationary signal - a signal whose frequency varies with time. For example, a signal like this: -

Performing the DFT on this signal yields an amplitude spectrum that suggests that 5 Hz and 8 Hz are present.

However, we cannot tell from the amplitude spectrum alone where the 5 Hz content is temporally, nor where the 8 Hz content is temporally. Peforming the STFT of the signal gives us a colorized plot that shows us that from 0 to 400 ms, 5 Hz has a strong presence, and from 400 ms to 1 s 8 Hz has a strong presence.

This is all good, we can see when which frequencies are present, but my question is why do we need the STFT? It's true that I cannot tell when the frequency content is temporally from the amplitude spectrum alone, but if I have the phase spectrum as well I can recover the time-domain signal without any loss of information (because the Fourier Transform is linear), and from there I can see the how the frequency changes as a function of time. So why even bother with the STFT?

A simple example is human hearing. You hear musical notes changing with time and the STFT can easily show that. The DFT of the entire piece of music isn't particularly useful.

If the signal is very very long, let's say it's minutes long, the spectrum at the end of the signal is likely to be very different from the spectrum at the beginning of the signal.
Especially in audio, we just don't give a rat's ass about what the spectrum is ten seconds, or even two seconds, in the past or in the future when we're working with the half-second of audio in the present time.
The STFT is not about what the global spectrum is, it's about what the local spectrum is.  And the collection of all of these local spectra is precisely what the STFT is.

Just FYI, here is a formal definition of the STFT that I sorta rewrote from the lit to use windows that are centered at 0.
